# New to Javascript, im wondering why

Tags: javascript

My code doesnet add number like 2+2=4 , its adds it like 2+2=22.
I was wondering how I could change this so that it recognizes that my variables are numbers.

```
var gra=0;
var graTwo=0;
var graThree=0;

var stu = prompt("Who are you grading?");
var gra = prompt("Oh, what is " +stu+ "'s grade?") 
    if(gra>80) {
    alert("Congrats, " +stu+   ". Have a gold star!")
    }
        else {
            alert("Wow, thats awful " +stu+  ", try again")
        };
var stuTwo = prompt("Who are you grading?")
var graTwo = prompt(" Oh, what is " +stuTwo+ " 's grade?")
            if(graTwo>80) {
            alert("Congrats, " +stuTwo+ ". Have a gold star!")
    }
        else {
            alert("Wow, thats awful " +stuTwo+ ", try again")
        };
var stuThree = prompt("Who are you grading?");
var graThree = prompt("Oh, what is" +graThree+ "'s grade?")
            if(graThree>80) {
    alert("Congrats, " +stuThree+ ". Have a gold star!");
            }
        else {
            alert("Wow, thats awful " +stuThree+ ", try again")
        };
var add = (gra+graTwo+graThree);
alert(add)
    alert("The average grade of your class is ")
```

Comment: Next time try to do a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/), for javascript you could also share a live example with http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3):

You aren't having trouble because of the pluses. You are having trouble because you are assigning graThree to a prompt, which is a string. Use parseInt as the other answer suggests.

Also, you are prompting `prompt("Oh, what is" + graThree+ "'s grade?")` when you should be using the variable `stuThree`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! I'm still wondering how I change it so it adds up the numbers mathematically instead of pushing them together.

Comment: If each one is being parsed as an int as myself and some others have suggested (`parseInt`), they will be integers and so will add up mathematically. Your problem is that the return value of `prompt` is going to be a string, so you are concatenating three strings together instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: It absolutely is an answer, and a correct answer. The OP stated that he/she was new to Javascript, I'd rather point them in the right direction than rewrite their code for them.

Comment: Where would I put these?

Comment: You could wrap your prompt calls, e.g. var graThree = parseInt(prompt(...)), but only the ones that are returning numbers. Alternatively, assign the prompt output to a variable, like var graThreeStr = prompt(...), then var graThree = parseInt(graThreeStr);

Comment: They a bunch! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt function returns string types so your addition concatenates strings instead of adding numbers.
You should always be sure of your variable types before performing any action on them.
Javascript can be a little too nice sometimes.